# redis-cli is not working

Tags: redis

I've used redis-cli before (not sure if on this box), but now it's giving me this:

```
nak@none:~$ redis-cli
usage: redis-cli [-h host] [-p port] [-r repeat_times] [-n db_num] cmd arg1 arg2 arg3 ... argN
usage: echo "argN" | redis-cli [-h host] [-p port] [-r repeat_times] [-n db_num] cmd arg1 arg2 ... arg(N-1)

If a pipe from standard input is detected this data is used as last argument.

example: cat /etc/passwd | redis-cli set my_passwd
example: redis-cli get my_passwd
example: redis-cli -r 100 lpush mylist x
```

So, I netcat to the redis server and am able to communicate:

```
nak@none:~$ ncat 127.0.0.1 6379
info
$336
redis_version:1.2.0
arch_bits:32
multiplexing_api:epoll
uptime_in_seconds:332
uptime_in_days:0
connected_clients:1
etc...
```

I've tried specifying IP and port: `redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379` (without success)
Not a big deal, but weird.
Any ideas as to why this is happening? Thanks stackoverflow!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your "info" you are using redis 1.2, which is a really old version. That version may not have supported interactive cli. I cannot confirm since that version is not even in the repository.

Comment: You're right, I was going to answer my own question last night but the connection went down. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

the version 1.2 seems to be to old:

Visit http://www.redis.io/download and if you are using ubuntu you can follow this guide http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Redis or https://askubuntu.com/questions/68576/how-does-one-upgrade-redis-2-2-to-2-4